# How can I output a Dataframe to a specific json?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

i am doing a practice to proccess some financial transactions.
Here is what data is Excel. There is 2 transactions.

As you can see one transaction is include many record(one row in one record).
And they have different Trans_num (101,102)

```
          Date  Tracs num    Disscription      Debit     Credit  Account id
0   2017-01-31        101         Open Up  371275.83        NaN        1213
1   2017-01-31        101         Open Up   38052.22        NaN        1214
2   2017-01-31        101         Open Up   11000.00        NaN        2112
3   2017-01-31        101         Open Up    2000.00        NaN        2113
4   2017-01-31        101         Open Up   28017.00        NaN        2114
5   2017-01-31        101         Open Up  226940.00        NaN        2116
6   2017-01-31        101         Open Up        NaN 4490786.58        2211
7   2017-01-31        101         Open Up        NaN  421161.86        2212
8   2017-01-31        101         Open Up        NaN    3930.00        2213
9   2017-01-31        101         Open Up  249991.15        NaN        2712
10  2017-01-31        101         Open Up 3219067.10        NaN        3611
11  2017-01-31        101         Open Up  134415.00        NaN        4121
12  2017-01-31        101         Open Up    1235.00        NaN        4211
13  2017-01-31        101         Open Up    2776.02        NaN        4221
14  2017-01-31        101         Open Up    3043.47        NaN        4222
15  2017-01-31        102  January Income    3500.00        NaN        1213
16  2017-01-31        102  January Income        NaN   11330.00        2211
17  2017-01-31        102  January Income        NaN    5944.00        2212
18  2017-01-31        102  January Income   11330.00        NaN        6313
19  2017-01-31        102  January Income    1580.00        NaN        6319
20  2017-01-31        102  January Income     840.00        NaN        6322
21  2017-01-31        102  January Income      24.00        NaN        6521
```

I use Pandas to read it all in Excel.
[image: img]

Here is a question, I need to merge all record in a list, so how can i split them to this fomat? Thanks a lot.

```
[
Date : "2017-01-31"
Tracs_num : "101"
Disscription : "Open Up"
Data : [371275.83, 0, 1213],[38052.22,0,1214]...
],
[
Date : "2017-01-31"
Tracs_num : "102"
Disscription : "January Income"
Data : [3500, 0, 1213],[0,11300,1214]...
]
```

Comment: please post code and data, not images of code and data.

Comment: Your suggested output looks weird, should it be a list of dicts instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some dummy data, you can use something like this to get your desired output (change change the column names etc):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=n), 'Trans_num': np.random.randint(10,100,n), 'Debit':np.random.randint(10,100,n), 'Credit':np.random.randint(10,100,n) })
# list_ = df.to_dict('records')

list_ = []
for name,group in df.groupby(['date', 'Trans_num']):
    data = list(zip(group['Debit'].to_list(), group['Credit'].to_list()))
    list_.append({'Date': str(name[0].date()), 'Trans_num': name[1], 'Data': data})
list_
```

Output:

```
[{'Date': '2023-01-01', 'Trans_num': 34, 'Data': [(73, 12)]},
 {'Date': '2023-01-02', 'Trans_num': 13, 'Data': [(90, 26)]},
 {'Date': '2023-01-03', 'Trans_num': 17, 'Data': [(19, 61)]},
...
```

Comment: It is great method ! But when I use this method, the two output "Data" is same. In fact they are different. How can I solove it, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry small typo in my code... updated it now. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a list of *dicts*, you can use :

```
meta = ["Date", "Tracs num", "Disscription"]
data = ["Debit", "Credit", "Account id"]

out = [
    {
        "Date": da,
        "Tracs_num": tr,
        "Description": de,
        "Data": [*g[data].to_numpy().tolist()]
    } for (da, tr, de), g in (
        pd.read_excel("file.xlsx").fillna({"Credit": 0, "Debit": 0})
        .astype({"Date": "str", "Tracs num": "str"}).groupby(meta, sort=False)
    )
]
```

Output :

```
import json

print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))

[
    {
        "Date": "2017-01-31",
        "Tracs_num": "101",
        "Description": "Open Up",
        "Data": [
            [371275.83, 0.0, 1213.0],
            [38052.22, 0.0, 1214.0]
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "Date": "2017-01-31",
        "Tracs_num": "102",
        "Description": "January Income",
        "Data": [
            [3500.0, 0.0, 1213.0],
            [0.0, 11330.0, 2211.0]
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```